# transform: translateY Not Working on Style Attribute in IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

We are implementing a simple frozen header for tabular data in our application, using this basic function:

```
$('.wrapper').on('scroll', function () {
  var translate = "translateY(" + this.scrollTop + "px)";
  this.querySelector('thead').style.transform = translate;
});
```

It works fine in Chrome/Firefox, and it does apply the right transform to the thead element's style attribute, but it doesn't seem to actually apply the transform in IE/Edge.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLwgcsag/1/

[Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) states that IE11/Edge both support it without prefixes, so is this a bug, and if so, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use CSS to keep the headers fixed instead? Select the tr that holds the headers, and add the following to it:

```
#trHeader {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: That breaks the column alignment and sets the header on top of the first row, so it's not really an option since we're not going to set fixed widths on columns, fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/xLwgcsag/3/